# Pass value to a php file to change the text inside the file then force download the same file

Tags: php

Download link:

```
<a href="download.php?words=2000&sort=popular&type=xml">Download php file</a>
```

download.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>PHP file</h1>

<?php
function get_text($text)  
{  
   ....
}      

function get_time($time)  
{  
   ....
}    

$url = "http://api.xxx.com/info.php?words=".$_GET['words']."&sort=".$_GET['sort']."&type="$_GET['type'];
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
if (count($xml))
{
  foreach($xml->book as $book)
  {
    echo ....      
  }
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

The download.php is a ready made API php script to provide webmasters upload to their FTP. Webmasters can be choose many options(e.g: download.php?words=2000&sort=popular&type=xml) from a form, then submit the form to get their custom API script.

This is the line that will replace the options after they submit the form.:

```
$url = "http://api.xxx.com/info.php?words=".$_GET['words']."&sort=".$_GET['sort']."&type="$_GET['type'];
```

This is the code to force download. But i don't know how to wrap whole page with $content = "";. I know how to wrap the HTML codes but how to wrap the PHP function and codes on the page?

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="download.php");
print $content;
```

Comment: Can you please define `wrap` in `... how to wrap the PHP function and codes on the page` ?

Comment: Hi, because i have to print $content; to get the specific parts on the page. So, as far i know is $content = "content that i want to print.";. But i don't know how to wrap the php: $content = "<?php function get_text($text) {....";

Comment: Simply escape the characters that causes it to be handled as php. So for example, when you are showing stuff in a HTML file, you could start by making from every  `<` an `&lt;`. For this kind a stuff you can use functions like [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php). You just have to figure out what charset you are using and how you are presenting it.

Comment: So you are actually trying to give the user the entire source that would be otherwise output by `download.php`? Should I care that you have `type=json` in your example but the file actually uses XML?

Comment: Hi mike, nope, please ignore the json type.

Comment: Hi jelmer, thanks. I will take a look the html decode. Do you have any idea to improve the code(header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="download.php");
print $content;) without using the HTML decode?

Comment: You don't need to wrap anything. Since the file is being downloaded as an attachment, not loaded into the browser, it will just be saved as is. You should use `file_get_contents()` instead of `simplexml_load_file()` if you don't want to parse the data as XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that is what yo want; but you could create a second script that calls the first one, gets the output, and sends that with the mentioned headers:

```
<?php
$words = (int) $_GET['words'];
$sort = $_GET['sort'];

$url = sprintf("http://localhost/wherever/download.php?words=%d&sort=%s&type=xml", $words, $sort);
$content = file_get_contents($url);

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="download.php");
print $content;
?>
```

Call that file "force_download.php" and let the users call `<a href="force_download.php?words=2000&sort=popular&type=xml">Download php file</a>` instead.